# Getting ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis error but there are nothing missing as such

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below procedure for altering a table to add new partition. but when I execute this, I am getting the error:

> ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

I can't find the actual reason. Can any one help me please?

```
create or replace procedure mydaily_partition 
is
highest_value varchar2(100):='2171-01-02 00:00:00';
date_format varchar2(100) :='SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
table_name varchar2(100) := 'dup_check_table';
partition_name varchar2(100) :='p1';
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name ||' add partition '|| partition_name ||' values less than '||(TO_DATE('2019-01-02 00:00:00','SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

--dbms_output.put_line('completed');
COMMIT;
end;
```

Comment: Tip: when you have problems executing a concatenated string, print out the command you are really trying to execute. That way you can *see* missing spaces, quotes, brackets etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `to_date()` call is not part of your generated ALTER table statement.

Currently your string concatenation results in something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE foo add partition bar values less than 02-JAN-19;
```

(the actual outcome depends on your NLS settings).

What you want to have is:

```
ALTER TABLE foo add partition bar values less than (TO_DATE('2019-01-02 00:00:00','SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

To achieve that, you need to put the `to_date()` call *inside* the single quotes. In order to embed single quotes in string literal you need to duplicate them, so your execute immediate should look like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name ||
    ' add partition '|| partition_name ||
    ' values less than '||'(TO_DATE(''2019-01-02 00:00:00'',''SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS''))';
```

To incorporate your variables, you need to concatenate them into the string:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name ||
    ' add partition '|| partition_name ||
    ' values less than '||'(TO_DATE('''||highest_value||''','''||date_format||'''))';
```

Comment: thanks, this works fine, but when I replace the date string with variuable 'highest_value' and 'date_format, I am getting same error. could you please update this answer using the declared variables for date and date format ? thanks in advance

Comment: @Msn: just concatenate them, but make sure you have single quotes _inside_ the string. See my edit

Answer (score 4):

> table_name varchar2(100) := 'dup_check_table;

Missing a `'` before the `;` and include your to date into your string query.

Here the fix:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mydaily_partition
IS
   highest_value    VARCHAR2 (100) := '2171-01-02 00:00:00';
   date_format      VARCHAR2 (100) := 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
   table_name       VARCHAR2 (100) := 'dup_check_table';
   partition_name   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'p1';
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   'ALTER TABLE '
                    || table_name
                    || ' add partition '
                    || partition_name
                    || ' values less than (TO_DATE ('''
                    || highest_value
                    || ''','''
                    || date_format
                    || '''))';

   --dbms_output.put_line('completed');
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. still I am getting the same error.

Comment: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
ORA-06512: at "BTGERAPPSANITY.MYDAILY_PARTITION", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 2

Comment: Get your date between parenthesis

Comment: could u please update ur answer as u said? (with parenthesis)

Comment: @Febienne B, now another error, ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06512: at "BTGERAPPSANITY.MYDAILY_PARTITION", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 2

Comment: thanks, this works fine, but when I replace the date string with variuable 'highest_value' and 'date_format, I am getting same error. could you please update this answer using the declared variables for date and date format ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure mydaily_partition
  2  is
  3  highest_value varchar2(100):='2171-01-02 00:00:00';
  4  date_format varchar2(100) :='SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
  5  table_name varchar2(100) := 'dup_check_table';
  6  partition_name varchar2(100) :='p1';
  7  begin
  8  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name ||' add partition '|| partition_name ||' values less than '||(TO_DATE('2019-01-02 00:00:00','SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
  9  
 10  --dbms_output.put_line('completed');
 11  COMMIT;
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
create or replace procedure mydaily_partition 
is
    highest_value varchar2(100):='2171-01-02 00:00:00';
    date_format varchar2(100) :='SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
    table_name varchar2(100) := 'dup_check_table';
    partition_name varchar2(100) :='p1';
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'{ALTER TABLE :tbl add partition :part_name values less than TO_DATE('2019-01-02 00:00:00','SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))}'
    using table_name , partition_name;

--dbms_output.put_line('completed');
COMMIT;
end;
```